# make a requestLocationUpdate on android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location

**Backgroud**

I want to create an tracking application. The user will able to chose one point as their destination point. Once the user hit the start button, the application will determine the user current location and will end at the destination selected by the user just now.

**Problem**

I have manage to put 2 marker on the map. One as the destination point and the other is the current location of the user. I have problem on making the current location marker to move once the user move. What I mean is that, I want the marker to move on the map once the user start to move. It mean that the application will detect the user location until they arrive at their destination.

**Code**

I'm currently use the function `requestLocationUpdate`. But the issue is, I don't really how that function. There are few example that I see, but I don't understand all the example.

here is how my requestLocationUpdate look like:

```
public void locupdate() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, this.getClass());  
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 45000,5,pi);
}
```

Here is how I call the method:

```
public void updateCurrentLocation(View v){
    gps.locupdate();
}
```

the updateCurrentLocation is an android:onClick for a button. Once the user press the button, the application will start to update the location every 45. That is what I'm expecting. How to implement it to the marker and make the marker change it location every 45 second ?  One more thing that I still confuse, how does the `requestLocationUpdates` method really work.

So, can anyone here help me to solve this issue ? Am I on the right path or there is other method that I should use. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(45000)         // 45 seconds
            .setFastestInterval(16)    // 16ms = 60fps
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

and implement interface `LocationListener`

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
}
```

Comment: can you explain more about how to use your code ? I'm new to this android application.

Comment: @MAJ i use it when work with Google Maps. But doesn't matter. In your Activity implement interface LocationListener

and by using REQUEST you can check location every 45 sec

Comment: can u give me the sample code of yours ? i really need it as the reference.

Comment: can you give the sample code or any reference that relate with the topic ?

Comment: @MAJ look extras/google/google_play_services/samples/map folder in your sdk directory. There is the sample of using location

Comment: is the sample code in the directory cannot be imported to the eclipse ? @Suvitruf